# opencart cannot save setting after renaming admin folder

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have problem with opencart 2(latest)
so, I renamed admin folder to "secret" then adjusted secret/config.php to :

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://domain.com/secret/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://domain.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://domain.com/secret/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://domain.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/domain/public_html/secret/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/domain/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/domain/public_html/secret/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/domain/public_html/secret/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/domain/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/domain/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/domain/public_html/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/domain/public_html/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/domain/public_html/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/domain/public_html/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/domain/public_html/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/domain/public_html/catalog/');
```

I also enabled seo url friendly.
but after that, I cannot save settings, when I clicked button save, it was always been redirected to "The page you requested cannot be found." . I don't know with another pages, I haven't try yet.

do I miss something?. I need your advise,
thank you.

Comment: Do you have vQmod or OCmod?

Comment: no, I don't install vqmod yet.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file  - I think there could be something in there to try to exclude `admin` from being used as an SEO friendly URL. You may need to change this to exclude `secret` instead.

Comment: don't try to rename the admin folder, it will just give you a headache and there are many functions internally which rely on the default name "admin".  if you are doing this for security there are better ways like htpasswd, ip access restrictions, fail2ban, etc

Answer (score 0):

You also have to rename the admin folder in `system/startup.php`. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Also remove all file / folder from `system\storage\modification` except index.html

Comment: @ali , I've tried what you mentioned, and also in some files like secret/controller/extension/modification.php , secret/controller/openbay/amazon_product.php and amazonus_product.php , still not work.

Comment: @munjal I just found file index.html on system/storage/modification, nothing else.

Comment: Try to echo the path where save button takes you to.